# Loading charts on a PhoneGap based application using GWT Google APIs

Tags: android, gwt, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm using [GWT visualisation API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted). The charts work well in a browser, but they don't on an Android based PhoneGap application.
In fact, I'm using the generated code from a GWT project to create the UI.
When logging the application on a simulator, I remarked that a part of code is not executed and this code is inserted in a new Runnable called by the main thread.

```
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(threadName, packagesToLoad);
```

I doubt that this is because PhoneGap doesn't support multi-threading, because the generated JavaScript code is executed in a single thread.

So have you any idea how to solve the problem?
Or is there any other method to be called to draw charts using Visualisation Google API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the Internet connection!
In fact, I have a difficulty to connect the Android emulator to the Internet in my office behind a proxy, so I decided to test the application at home and it works. **But** I find another problem when viewing some Charts (LineChart, PieChart) on the emulator even from the [google web site demo](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html). 
Is there any equivalent library to GWT that creates pretty charts, without the need of coding JavaScript?

Comment: After reading the Android docs, I found that Android 2.2 doesn't support SVG so I decided to move to drawing Flash plots for Android.